# Flutter: Execute next steps after the on before finished

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I used the BLOC architecture inside my app. One method inside my bloc resolves a picked address-ID from a listView and return the city name. After this I want my Text-Editing-Controller to have this picked value and show it on the texteditingfield:

The BlocA uses a simple ID and look it up using Google-Places API. BlocA then return a new state with the resolved address as a state property. Running the code below did not show the correct city after tapping on a listView-item.

Await do not work unfortunately.

```
// ListView.builder code
onTap: () {
context
       .read<BlocA>()
       .add(PickAddress(id: state.searchResults[index].placeId));
FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(); //hide Keyboard
_textController.value = TextEditingValue(text: state.address.city);
```

Answer (score 0):

the code its not clear enough
remember to use "await" you have to set Async on onTap like this

```
onTap: () async { ....
```

if you did that and still not working send the whole code

Comment: Using async/await is not required here. There's no reason for the onTap function to wait for the Bloc to handle the event to complete.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what your Bloc actually returns? Use the debugger and step through your code to see what actually happens in your code.

When it comes to using Bloc's to build your state you usually don't access the state with by calling .state.

The line `_textController.value = TextEditingValue(text: state.address.city);` is not the way you access your state. When the Bloc sends the new state, the widget will rebuild and render based on the new state.